webpack-dev-server error: "Cannot GET / "
I am trying to run a Webpack Dev Server. I am using TypeScript.
I receive the following error when I open my http://localhost:8080/ I receive the error:
Cannot GET /
Here is my webpack.config.js file:
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')]
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
 
};

Here is my package.json :
{
  "name": "vault",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "typescript": "^5.6.2",
    "webpack": "^5.95.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.1.0"
  }
}


Here is my *tsconfig.json *:
{
  "name": "vault",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "typescript": "^5.6.2",
    "webpack": "^5.95.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.1.0"
  }
}


And my folder structure:
Folder structure

"webpack-dev-server" is no longer supported. Try changing it to:
"serve": "webpack serve",

Thank you, I've fixed that part! The problem persists though, so something else is wrong. Error remains the same.
